# Reverting a pull request completely

Tags: git, github, merge, git-revert

Current `master` has been worked on for the past month. Also a branch called `contract` has been worked on simultaneously.

`contract` was merged into `master` by mistake. 100 commits, with dates that overlap `master` commits that already existed.

How can I completely remove the pull request that merged all 100 commits from `contract` into `master`?

We did a GitHub revert on the pull request, and that removed the code but not the history. Now when we attempt to do a mock pull request of merging `contract` into `master` it shows there are no changes. (I assume because those commits already went in but were reverted?)

There have been no commits on `master` after the merge aside from the revert.

How can I completely remove any commits added by the pull request, and still allow them to go in successfully when we eventually do merge `contract` into `master`?

Comment: Have any other commits been made since the revert, or between the merge and the revert?

Comment: No commits were made between the merge and then revert. Only 2 were made after the merge and revert but both of those commits went into contract not master

Answer (score 6):

Your history might look something like this:

```
*--*--*--C---A--B [master]
 \          /
  *--*--*--*--* [contract]
```

Where `A` is the bad merge, `B` is the revert, and `C` is the last good commit before the merge. (To determine what the hashes are for your case, do e.g. `git log --oneline --decorate`.)

When you revert a merge, Git takes that to mean that you never want those changes to be re-merged into the repository. If you were just working from the command line, the solution is to revert the revert, see: [Re-doing a reverted merge in Git](//stackoverflow.com/a/1078209/2747593). However, that would prevent you from using GitHub's PR UI.

Instead, you can rewrite history. Obligatory **WARNING**: rewriting history can be dangerous and disruptive for other developers using your repository. Be sure to communicate clearly that you are doing so.

If you haven't already, switch to `master` (`git checkout master`).

If you don't have any commits after `C` aside from `A`, `B`, and any commits from `contract`, then do:

```
git reset --hard HEAD~2
```

Or:

```
git reset --hard C
```

Then your history will look like this:

```
*--*--*--C [master]
 \          
  *--*--*--*--* [contract]
```

If there have been more commits in the meantime, then you will have to rebase instead. Do:

```
git rebase -i X
```

In the `rebase-todo` file, delete any lines that correspond to the `contract` branch, as well as the revert commit `B`. (In my testing, the merge commit `A` wasn't shown, but remove that if it is.) If there are any conflicts, fix them and continue with `git rebase --continue`.

After you're done rewriting history, do:

```
git push --force-with-lease origin master
```

Your `master` branch will now have no evidence that the merge ever took place, and a PR from `contract` should show all the expected commits.

Comment: After I did this I still had the commits in `master` that `contract` had (100 or so) but I no longer had `A` or `B` (the merge request or the revert)... I went to pull request `contract` into `master` and it still showed there were no changes.  I imagined if this was a squash and merge it would of reverted all those 100 commits

Comment: Hmm that's weird. Was it a fast-forward merge? If there are no good commits in between, then you'll just need to `reset` a little farther back. Find the last good commit and do `git reset --hard <sha>`.

Comment: Unfortunately there are good commits between. It was a standard merge via github. Not sure which type they use

Comment: @LearningJrDev Okay. I'm still confused about how that happened, but I've updated my answer to address to provide another solution.